# Find $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{{{3^n} + {5^n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find the limit 
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{{{3^n} + {5^n}}}.$$

Thanks.

Comment: What is bigger: $3$ or $5$? Think about it.

Answer (score 4):

I think simple inequalities give a better intuition of what's going on,

\begin{align}
5=\sqrt[n]{5^n}\leq \sqrt[n]{3^n+5^n} \leq\sqrt[n]{5^n+5^n} = 5\sqrt[n]{2} \to 5
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{{{3^n} + {5^n}}}=5\times\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[1+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}= 5.$$